# Change Color Collapse / Expand

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, look-and-feel

is there a way to change the color under the expand/collapse bar when highlighting a procedure?
In dark mode(twilight) I'm not able to see the beginning and the end of the subprocedure.

[image]

Comment: it's not clear what you're referring to, can you provide a more demonstrative picture?

Comment: Below the standard mode, https://bbcode0.com/full/2021/12/13/2faf5d14724c5313f6212f4acc6a8d54-full.png.html . if I the cursor's position is on the header of the subprocedure, mark the beginning and the end in blue.  Twilight is not possible to see it